# Как изменить код, чтобы можно было загружать PDF файлы?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, content-type

Всем привет. Есть следующий код, запускается машина состояний, берется фото от пользователя и два текстовых значения. Как изменить код, чтобы можно было брать не фото, а документ, допустим pdf? Спасибо!

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="Добавить", state=None)
async def cm_start(message : types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        await FSMAdmin.photo.set()
        await message.reply('Добавить новый файл')
    
#Ловим первый ответ от пользователя
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=FSMAdmin.photo)
async def load_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Теперь назови данный файл')
```

Comment: думаю, нужно вместо `photo` использовать `document`

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/download_file.html